# Idiom for incomplete investigation

Tags: phrases, idioms

What is the best idiom to describe improper investigation?

Scenario- the investigation was improper and hence prejudicial to the accused.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say **The investigation was carried out in a slipshod manner and thus proved prejudicial to the accused**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.